SelectTemplate not getting called for DataTemplateSelector C# wpf
I have a datatemplateselector.It is used to invoke two templates based on the value of a notificationtype.  But SelectTemplate not getting called. Why it is so.
    public class NotificationTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ErrorTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate InformationTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(
        object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        DataTemplate selectedTemplate = InformationTemplate;

        if (!(item is NotificationArgs))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not Valid!");
        }
        var selectedItem = (NotificationArgs)item;

        if (selectedItem.NotificationType == NotificationType.Information)
        {
            selectedTemplate = InformationTemplate;
        }
        else if(selectedItem.NotificationType==NotificationType.Error)
        {
            selectedTemplate = ErrorTemplate;
        }

        return selectedTemplate;
    }
}

NewView:-

<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1"  
                Background="Red" Padding="10">
            <TextBlock Width="350"  
                       TextAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding NotificationMessage}"
                       FontSize="15" 
                       Foreground="White" 
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center">

            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="InformationTemplate">
        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1"  
                Background="Blue" Padding="10">
            <TextBlock Width="350"  
                       TextAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding NotificationMessage}"
                       FontSize="15" 
                       Foreground="White" 
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <configCreatorNotification:NotificationTemplateSelector x:Key ="NotificationTemplateSelector"
                                          ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"
                                          InformationTemplate="{StaticResource InformationTemplate}" />

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding  Notification}" 
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource NotificationTemplateSelector}">

    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>

MainView:-
<Grid Grid.Column="1" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Visibilty}">

    <views:NotificationView >
        </views:NotificationView>
</Grid>

Viewmodel:-
Notification = new ObservableCollection<NotificationArgs>();
var notificationService = new NotificationService(obj =>
{
    NotificationMessage = obj.Message;
    Notification.Add(obj);
}

Please help why the selectTemplate() is not getting invoked. Also instaed of Itemscontrol can I just refer a class object instead of a collection. For that which control I have to use. because my binding happens at runtime and collection data is not hardcoded.
public ObservableCollection<NotificationArgs> Notification
{
    get => _notification;
    set => SetPropertyValue(ref _notification, value, nameof(Notification));
}


Are you perhaps looking for ContentControl, where you can set the ContentTemplateSelector property?

Besides that, are you saying that Notification.Add(obj) does actually add an item to the ItemsControl, but without calling the ItemTemplateSelector?



</ItemsControl>

  This code I have added in view. What additional thing I have to do. This code I got frm stackoverflow

What are you trying to say? That XAML fragment is already in your question. Is an item added or not?

an item is added using the Notification.add(obj). But it is not invoking selecttemplate

What I am asking is whether an item actually appears in the ItemsControl. Is there anything shown? You need to show us your view model, too.

How to check whether item is there in itemscontrol? I have pasted my view model also

By looking at your computer screen. And you have not shown your view model. We have no idea how the Notification property is declared. You should also explain whether the ItemsControl should ever show more than one item. Should it or not? Would a ControlControl perhaps be more suitable?

I have added in the last code, how notification is declared

Now we also need to know how exactly you access the view model instance in the DataContext of the UserControl. Where is the DataContext set? Are you sure you only have one instance of the view model? How do you call the code that updates the Notification property?

The reason SelectTemplate was not called is instead of itemscontrol we have to use contentcontrol. Now call is coming. But the value is null in item
